# Calculating area between three curves- Absolute values?

Tags: calculus

**The question:**

> Consider the region bounded by $y=x$, $y=x/4$, and $y=1/x$. Set up the integrals with respect to $x$ for the areas of this region. Do not solve the integral.

**My attempt.**
I have found the bounds to be between $-2$ and $-1$ for $x/4$ and $1/x$; $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$  for $x$ and $x/4$; and $1$ and $2$ for $1/x$ and $x/4$. I just need help figuring out which function should come first in each integral.

For the first integral with the bounds $-2$ and $-1$, I have set $[(x/4)-(1/x)]dx$ but the answer key provided by my instructor has it backwards. Is there any case where I should consider absolute values?

As a separate question, it also asks to set up the integrals in terms of $y$. How should I go about that?

Comment: That's puzzling. I would do the same as you, assuming we are integrating from $-2$ to $-1$ and want each of the two regions bounded by the curves to have positive area. I don't see any indication that we should compute a negative area for that region.

Comment: How about $\int_0^1x-\frac x4\,dx+\int_1^2\frac1x-\frac x4dx$ for the area of one of the regions? Then multiply this answer by 2 to get the area of the entire region assuming you want positive area.

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/area-between-curves-calculator/area%20x%2C%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%2C%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B4%7D?or=input

Comment: The answers provided by my instructor are consistent with what is provided by the link above. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Aha, that link is very helpful. If you apply the absolute value inside the integral, you get a positive area. Note that $\lvert \frac1x - \frac x4\rvert = \lvert \frac x4 - \frac 1x\rvert$. So if you happen to subtract the greater quantity from the lesser one, resulting in a negative value, the absolute value sign turns it into a positive value.

Comment: Okay, so as a rule of thumb should I always take the absolute value of the area between curves when it is negative?

Comment: The absolute value means you don't have to remember which curve has the greater $y$ values. It would not be my style but if it is your professor's style then you should follow it. It is a good method.

Comment: Would it be fine if I subtract the integral instead of adding it? Kind of like when working through a net change problem (distance vs displacement)

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind when you say "subtract the integral". Usually when integrating area between curves I would want the integral to be positive. If you're integrating something where the result is not really an area, but you remember that people talk about the integral of any function as the "area under the graph of the function", then when the curve goes below the $x$ axis you'll have some "negative area". But you still don't subtract that part of the integral from the other parts. I think that's a different kind of problem than this one, however.